# BC30456: 'DataItem' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'

Tags: .net, asp.net, listview, updatepanel

I used to have the UpdatePanel as a wrapper for the whole Listview item. Which was not correct as an AJAX logic.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate> 
                '....
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers></Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So i decided that i should wrap only the group of ImageButtons with update panels as follows...

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" RenderMode="Block">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnContainsError" runat="server"/>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAttach" runat="server" CommandName='<%# "AddC_" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QID") & "_" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Label") %>'/>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnFavorite" runat="server" CommandName='<%# "AddF_" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QID")  & "_" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Label") %>'/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Image ID="btnStar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/star.png" Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InT") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And now i get the `'DataItem' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.` error.

So what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the

```
<%# Eval( "field" ) %>
```

shorthand

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this may fix your problem or not, but consider this:

Replace:  `Binder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field_NAME")`

with just this: `Eval("Field_NAME")`